# Passing data from page to page using System.Web.Caching.Cache

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to pass data from one asp.net page to another. I've seen that using System.Web.Caching.Cache is a good way to accomplish this. I'm wondering if it's a good way to do it and also is there any cleanup or other things I need to keep in mind when you the Cache?

I'm not passing very much, at most two integers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This says it better than I could have myself:

> In ASP.NET, there are several
>   different ways to persist data between
>   user requests—so many, in fact, that
>   the novice developer is often confused
>   about which object to use in a
>   particular situation. In order to
>   answer this question, there are three
>   criteria that should be considered:
>
> ```
> * Who needs the data?
> * How long does the data need to be persisted?
> * How large is the set of data?
> ```
>
> By answering these questions, you can
>   determine which object provides the
>   best solution for persisting data
>   between requests in an ASP.NET
>   application.

See [Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is not used for this purpose. Cached items are not stored for per session, it's stored just like `Application` collection, visible to each session at the moment. They are stored and accessed by all sessions. You should try to use `Session` for example.